# Getting data from database into a php array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, graph

I've been having an error for about 2 days now I'd appreaciate if someone could help me.

**Objective:**
I want to make a query that selects all payments in a month and save them in an array, I wanna graph this so I also need the days where no payments were done.

This is my code and I think my problem is when I try to catch them in an array. When I call my function from my main page all my website goes down.

```
 function getDailyGraph($membership, $selectedMonth){
       $sql = "SELECT rate_amount AS payment, DAY(date) AS day FROM payments WHERE membership_id = ".$membership.
      " AND MONTH(date) = ".$selectedMonth." ORDER BY day";
      $query = $db->query($sql);
      $days = array();
      for ($i=1; $i <= 31 ; $i++) { 
        $payment = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        # code...
        if ($i == $payment['day']) {
          # code...
          $days[] = $payment['payment'];
        }else{
          $days[] = 0;
        }
      }
        return $days;
  }
```

Comment: Hang on a second; are you using PDO or mysql_*? Because I see `$db->query($sql)` and `mysql_fetch_array($query)` in the same context...

Comment: Have a look at your error log. Change $payment['dia'] to $payment['day'].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have an infinite loop; your `$i+1` should be `$i+=1` or `$i++`, so your loop will never finish, which would result in a page never finishing/loading.

e: I posted too soon.

You also have a logic error in your code; you're selecting the days, but you're incrementing no matter what; if payments were only made on, say, the 10th, 15th, and 17th, you'll pull up three rows with dia 10, 15, 17, when your loop is on 1, 2, 3 and they can't possibly match.

Do the querying and day matching separately.

Do one loop as long as you get a result from `mysql_fetch_array` and store the resulting arrays; perhaps in another indexed by day, then loop over that and check the days you actually have available.

Comment: alright thanks, i think my text editor added that. Unfortunately the error's still there. Any other suggestions?

Comment: the thing is i actually want them not to match when my loop is on 1,2,3 (following your example). I want an array with 31 numbers at the end of my loop. cause when i graph them i need 31 points to graph the whole month. so if my loop is on 1 it will save a 0 in my array and i will graph that there were no payments on "october first". Is it still wrong that way?

Answer (score 0):

first of all, if you are using PDO, your code should be something like

```
$sql = 'SELECT rate_amount AS payment, DAY(date) AS day FROM payments WHERE membership_id = ".$membership." AND MONTH(date) = ".$selectedMonth." ORDER BY day';
foreach ($db->query($sql) as $payment) {
    //do something with $payment['dia'], $payment['payment'], etc...     
}
```

if you are using mysl_* functions, you should consider mysqli_* and your code should look like

```
$sql = 'SELECT rate_amount AS payment, DAY(date) AS day FROM payments WHERE membership_id = ".$membership." AND MONTH(date) = ".$selectedMonth." ORDER BY day';

/* connection to database */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_database");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* Select */
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
    //work with your data here
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        //do something with $payment['dia'], $payment['payment'], etc...
    }

    //free memory
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}else{
    echo "Error in query";
}
```